# Where do tmp files go after Bash finishes with a "local" variable?

Tags: bash, zsh, local-variables, tmp, file-recovery

I really screwed myself over recently.  I have a function which will swap the contents of two files:

```
function swap()         
{
    local TMPFILE=tmp.$$
    mv "$1" "$TMPFILE"
    mv "$2" "$1"
    mv "$TMPFILE""$2"
}               ^
```

As you can see right near where the carrot is pointing a space is missing.
As a result running the following command:

```
$ swap important.txt not-important.txt
```

causes important.txt to be overwritten by not-important.txt and important.txt is sent to the abyss of the local bash variable/file

Are there any options short of scraping the raw data on the disk?

```
$ grep -a -A1000 -B1000 "some text from important.txt" /dev/disk0
```

Comment: look for a /tmp folder . With a bit of luck, you OS comes up with tmpfiles like /tmp/tmp.1234, or from your script, I'd also look in the current directory, your home directory, your path, for files named tmp.*

Comment: Reading your script, I was assuming that TMPFILE=tmp.$$ was some bash builtin for tempfiles. But apparently it just puts "tmp.<pid>" into TMPFILE. Therefore, the tempfiles should be in the directory where you executed the command. Bad news here: if you used swap() several times in the same shell session, the name of the tempfile always remains the same (and thus the contents get overwritten in subsequent invocations)...

Comment: For future reference, you wanted `TMPFILE=$(mktemp)` to generate a new temp file name (in `/tmp/`, by default), each time `swap` is called. Also, you only want to perform each `mv` if the previous one succeeds, and (probably) abort the program if any of them fail: `mv "$1" "$TMPFILE" && mv "$2" "$1" && mv "$TMPFILE" "$2" || { echo "swap failed" >&2; exit 1; }`.

Comment: Thanks cephnar you've just illustrated a crucial point of Bash scripting which I hadn't previously understood.  The && operator and || operator can be thought of boolean logic "attempting" at a determinate evaluation.  So if one command fails in the context of a && tuple of commands then that 0 returned is enough to determine that the (sub)expression was false.  In the case of || the operation on the right side only executes if we haven't already determined the truthiness of the whole expression.

Answer (score 2):

The question makes no sense: Bash does not ever automatically delete files because it's done with a local variable. The variable is literally only a string that holds the name of the file -- it isn't a file handle in any meaningful way. (Bash *does* support real file handles, by using redirection to open files and track the associated FDs, or file descriptors, but your code here does nothing of the sort).

---

That is to say:

```
mv "$1" "$TEMPFILE"
```

renames your file *to the name already stored inside the TEMPFILE variable*. You know what that name is because you assign it in the line immediately prior:

```
local TMPFILE=tmp.$$
```

`$$` is the PID (or process ID) of the current shell... so `mv "$1" "$TEMPFILE"` could also have been written as `mv "$1" "tmp.$$"`. **The file contents are not stored in a local variable; only the *name* of the file is stored there.** Bash will not delete that file itself -- though if you call the function again in the same directory from a process with the same id, it will choose the same temporary file name, and thus will overwrite the file's prior contents.

---

Thus: In the case of your function `swap`, it will be leaving files around on-disk with names of the form `tmp.###`, where `###` is the PID of the bash instance running the script. If your contents still exist, they'll be in a file with a name matching that form.